# Need space between spans and border

Tags: html, xml

```
                                            <div class="row text-center mt8" >
                                            <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                                                <span>Familiarized with the production process</span>
                                                <span></span>
                                            </span>

                                            <div class="small8">
                                                <span>(signature)</span>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
```

Hi, I want to make this work. There must be text "Familiarz...." then there should be space, then border and it should be as long as the text is and after that signature. I tried adding spans and brs after text but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a trick you can add a fixer div. after the 'Familiarized...' span add a div class fixer with a little text:

```
    <div class="fixer">fix</div>
```

and give to him style:

```
    .fixer {
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: hidden;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

now you can add a `padding-bottom:10px` to a span and it will work fine.

the whole code is:

```
    <div class="row text-center mt8">

    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding-bottom: 10px;">Familiarized with the production process</span>

    <div class="fixer" style="display: inline-block;visibility:hidden;padding-bottom: 10px;">fix</div>

    <div class="small8">
        <span>(signature)</span>
    </div>

    </div>
```